# Launch browser based on url in docker output

Tags: bash, docker, shell, jupyter

I am launching a docker image using cmd/powershell, the docker image starts Jupyter lab, which has a URL in the output, I want to copy the URL and then launch the default browser with the URL

`docker run -p 8888:8888 -it "jupyter/lab"`

The output of the above command has some text with a URL:

```
[I 18:57:25.428 LabApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 18:57:25.542 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 18:57:25.542 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[W 18:57:25.545 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
[I 18:57:25.545 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 18:57:25.546 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 18:57:25.549 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tmp/dpcpp/release
[I 18:57:25.549 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:57:25.549 LabApp] http://(811378b194e4 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=9c260361ba75b9a2a70ad1e9eaa12155d628700382055274
[I 18:57:25.549 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 18:57:25.552 LabApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 18:57:25.552 LabApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://(811378b194e4 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=9c260361ba75b9a2a70ad1e9eaa12155d628700382055274
```

I want to launch browser with URL:
`http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=9c260361ba75b9a2a70ad1e9eaa12155d628700382055274`

I tried to write the output to a log file, and then parse the url in log file and use the start cmd to launch the URL in browser, but cant seem to get the url, the docker command does not return, its running the server.

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -it "jupyter/lab" > docker.log
URL=
start $URL
```